# Pull Custom /wp-admin/css for Non-Admin in Multisite

Tags: multisite

Here's a problem I'm sure many would like to find an answer to...

In a multi-site install, sometimes I would like blog owners to have their dashboard display differently style-wise. These styles are largely controlled by the /wp-admin/css/ folder.

The problem is that if we edit /wp-admin/css/, it impacts everybody - the MultiSite administrator included.

Is there a way to pull a custom /wp-admin/css/ folder for all site users other than the site owner? Thus allowing the site owner to still see the traditional panel and everybody else with a site inside the network to see a custom designed one controlled by stylesheets in /wp-admin/css/.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like the following should work:

```
global $blog_id;
if ($blog_id == 1) {
 wp_enqueue_style(
  'custom-style',
  '/wp-content/css/new_styles.css'
 );
}
```

Basically it checks if the person is on blog_id 1 and then loads the respective CSS from the CSS folder (you would need to create this).

This would go in your functions.php